# Comparing two C++ hex strings

Tags: c++, string, hex

If I have two std::strings which contain a hex value of arbitrary length, how can I compare to the two to see which one is larger in terms of value? Ideally I would like to avoid having to use a big number library.

I would like to do something like:

```
if(hex1 > hex2)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Are the values unsigned or signed?

Comment: You could simply read them as integer like this: std::cin >> std::hex >> hex1 >> hex2 in order to read them as hexadecimal integers and then compare them normally.

Comment: If the strings only contain [0-9], [a-f] or [A-F] make them lower-case (or upper-case) and compare as you do (if they have the same length).

Comment: Are they of the same length? Then a string compare will do. Otherwise the longest will be larger, unless it contains lots of initial 0's.

Comment: You didn't say how to get the value.  If they are a direct representation of the underlying bits of unsigned integers, then pad the shorter one on the left with zeroes. (Or if you know they have been left stripped of zeroes, just assume the longer one is bigger).

Comment: @baffo rasta - I would expect integer overflow with that attempt.

Comment: @KennyOstrom He could even try with strtol for converting the base and then compare, it would take less than iterating through both the strings to compare them.

Comment: These numbers are large, probably 256 or 512 bits, unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

You can do string comparison on these numbers but there are several potential problems which would have to be accounted for:

1. A sign character ("+0X2A" will be ordered before "0X0D")
2. The existence of a "0X" ("0X2A" will be ordered before "0D")
3. The capitalization of the "0X" ("0X2A" will be ordered before "0x0D")
4. The capitalization of hex digits ("0X0D" will be ordered before "0X0a")
5. The zero padding of numbers ("0X002A" will be ordered before "0X0D")

Consideration for all these conditions and their potential combinations will be a real headache. C++11 introduced the type [`unsigned long long int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types) which is at least a 64-bit unsigned integer. That gives you a whopping 16 hex characters worth of input, if your input is longer than that this won't work and you will have to parse the string.

```
if(stoll(hex1, 0, 16) > stoll(hex2, 0, 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `std::string`. Works for ASCII encoding.

```
bool hex_greater(std::string &first, std::string &second)
{
    /* Comprasions based on size */
    int firstSize = first.size(); 
    int secondSize = second.size();
    if(firstSize > secondSize)
        return true;
    else if(firstSize < secondSize)
        return false;

    /* Convert to lower case, for case insentitive comprasion */
    std::transform(first.begin(), first.end(), first.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::transform(second.begin(), second.end(), second.begin(), ::tolower);

    /* Call the std::string operator>(...) which compare strings lexicographically */
    if(first > second)
        return true;

    /* In other cases first hex string is not greater */
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Comparison on size may be false, in case of leading 0s.

Comment: This code assumes that `'9'` is less than `'a'`, which is not required by the language definition. It also assumes that the characters `'a'` through `'f'` are encoded as ascending values, which is also not required by the language definition. Those assumptions are valid if the characters are encoded in ASCII, but such an assumption must be stated in the answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker enhanced.

Answer (score 0):

Start by trimming leading zeroes.

If they are not equal length, then the longer one is greater.

If they are equal length, then loop through them from the beginning and compare each digit. Whichever string first has a larger digit in the same location as the other is greater.
If you get to the end and all digits are equal, then the values are equal.

Comment: you failed to account for two immediate problems already mentioned in comments

Comment: The longer one may no necessarily be greater if it has a whole bunch of leading zeros